# Perfect accuracy using normalized data pima indians dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset, normalization

I am dealing with a weird performance using `SVC` classifier in `sklearn`. I decided to use `kfold cross validation` in pima indians dataset. Since I wanted to try a SVC classifier I normalized the data using `MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))` to get features values between 0 and 1. But when I run the model I get 100% accuracy in each fold which obviously it is impossible. I looked for any error in the code but didn't come across with something strange. Here is my code. Any suggestion of this behaviour?

PD: I obviously load all needes libraries. I download the dataset from here https://gist.github.com/ktisha/c21e73a1bd1700294ef790c56c8aec1f and parse it to make things easier later on. Did I miss a step?

```
col_names = ['pregnant', 'glucose', 'bp', 'skin', 'insulin', 'bmi', 'pedigree', 'age', 'label']
pima = pd.read_csv("pima dataset.txt",names = col_names)
X = pima[col_names].as_matrix()
y = pima.label.as_matrix()
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
rescaledX = scaler.fit_transform(X)
# summarize transformed data
np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
#check transformations
print(rescaledX[0:5,:])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(rescaledX,y, test_size = 0.2, random_state =42)
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import random
clf_1 = SVC(random_state = 42) #create a default model
clf_1.fit(X_train, y_train) #fitting the model
r_svc = [random.randrange(1,1000) for i in range(3)] #create a random seed for the 3 simulations.
scores_matrix_clf_1 = []
for i in r_svc:
    kf = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle = True, random_state = i) 
    kf.get_n_splits(X)
    scores = cross_val_score(clf_1, X_train, y_train, cv=kf, n_jobs=-1, scoring = "accuracy")
    print('          SCORES FOR EACH RANDOM THREE SEEDS',i)
    print('-----------------------------SCORES----------------------------------------')
    print(scores, scores.mean())
    scores_matrix_clf_1.append(scores)
```

The output I am getting is this:

```
          SCORES FOR EACH RANDOM THREE SEEDS 617
-----------------------------SCORES----------------------------------------
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.] 1.0
          SCORES FOR EACH RANDOM THREE SEEDS 764
-----------------------------SCORES----------------------------------------
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.] 1.0
          SCORES FOR EACH RANDOM THREE SEEDS 395
-----------------------------SCORES----------------------------------------
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.] 1.0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help--100% accuracy with LibSVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155055/help-100-accuracy-with-libsvm)

Comment: Hi. I googled 'when I run the model I get 100% accuracy site:stackoverflow.com normalization'. Always google many clear, concise, specific versions/variants/phrasings of your question/problem/goal/desiderata with & without your specific strings/names/code and read many answers from many questions, which should inform your further googling. If you don't find an answer after applying what you learned and repeating this then ask a question. Use the most frequently productive keywords as tags. Use the best search as a title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `X` (input data set) contains the `label` column, which you are trying to predict. This is called [data leakage](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-leakage-machine-learning/) and almost always leads to 100% accuracy, because you are giving your estimator in one column (feature) an answer that you want to predict.

Example:

imagine that you have a data set containing the following features:

- human height
- human weight
- human foot size

and you want to predict `sex`.

So if you will feed `height`, `weight`, `foot size` **and** `sex` to your model as an input data set and `sex` (again) as an output vector, it will recognize that the last feature `sex` has the highest coefficient (weight) because it's always "predicts" correct sex.